# How to visualize in Google Maps a stream of data

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

Fellow Overflowers,

Am working in a project in which I need to place (pin) on map (Google in my case), a stream of data. One data record consist of 11 columns and the last 2 ones, are "city" and "country".

The data source is an html page, using the usual table tags, this is a business model and can not be changed. I managed to parse and analyze them using Nokogiri and finally store them in an array.

The idea is to pin each data in the map and ballon the rest of the 9 columns.

The hint: data are refreshed every 1 minute.

I can not figure out the approach: Shall i use arrays or a database to save the data? The average number of records to be displayed is 120 at the same time, on the map.

..and has anybody implemented something similar, could there be a comment regarding the performance?

Thanks a bunch...

Petros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will get problems when geocoding Country, City every minute. Probability you reach limit or encounter some failure is very high. The rest (refreshing with ajax and removing/adding 100+ markers) will be no problem.

So, if I'd do it I would created local database with geocodes (latitude and longitude) for Country+City. I would gather  geocodes (that is not present in database) via google.maps.Geocoder right in the javascript and send them back with AJAX to append to the table. I suppose, your country+city database get complete rapidly and you no need to extensive  geocoding anymore, also for exceptions you always have geocoder ready in javascript to resolve new city. It should work like a charm.

Alternative is to use [static geocoder](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) right in your server side just after you get new portion of data. But I would prefer first approach.

Comment: Hey confused-demon :)
Sorry, I was actually implementing, hehe. I have come across many issues actually, but yes, your guidance has been very valuable, thanks a lot!! I started by downloading the data from http://world-gazetteer.com/, but it proves that not every city is included. I have been investigating any meta-any-maps API for rails, heading for http://webification.com/tag/gmaps-rails. And finally, I am heading for http://earth-info.nga.mil/gns/html/namefiles.htm for city/country data.

Just for anyone who might be curious!
Thanks again!!